# Python selenium find element by xpath - cannot grab text

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

The following piece of code does not work and I have no idea why (this is within a table that is not within a frame, as least as far as I can tell). Can anybody please tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm sure it has to do with the "//" but I have no idea how to overcome this.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ifwinnertable'/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]").text
```

Comment: Try this - you are missing a closing bracket for first element - //*[@id='ifwinnertable']/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]

Comment: Can you share the relevant HTML DOM please for further analysis?